# How to query another table if this table do not have the requested data in dotnet core web API

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm sure there is a very simple solution to this but it seems I can't find a  solution. I have built a web API to return some data to the front end, but the problem is I want to access two tables to do that. If the first table do not have the requested data I need go to the next table, currently I am using simple `try catch` block; I know it a poor way to do it, so the code looks like this,

```
try
{
    var answers = await _context.OfferedAnswers.FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id == answerId);
    answerText = answers.Value;
}
catch (Exception)
{
    var answers = await _context.Cols.FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id == answerId);
    answerText = answers.Label;
}
```

Please can someone suggest me a better way to this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want to run `Cols.FirstOrDefaultAsync()` only when `OfferedAnswers.FirstOrDefaultAsync()` has failed or you don't mind where the result comes from?

Comment: Only when OfferedAnswers.FirstOrDefaultAsync() fails.

Comment: In that csse consider alessio's answer below. Does failure mean `answers` will be null or the `Value` property will be?

Comment: Answers will be, because there are no answer by the given ID, in that case query the next table (Cols).

Comment: In that case, alessio seems to be on the right track. Check for null before assigning to answersText. If it is null you check `Cols` as you were doing in your catch. You're right to have reservations about using try...catch for controlling program flow

Comment: how about you run both the query Asynchronously and check which has data and return that? That way if you don't have data in your first call you do not have to wait for another whole call to complete.

Comment: @Fabulous Yes, It worked. Don't know why I didn't think of that before. Thank you for the help. :)

Comment: @thebenman How do I do that? Can yo explain more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the answer is null before accessing its properties.
Like this:

```
If (answer == null)
....
```

Comment: Please include a little more to your answer

Comment: The exception he is catching is raised by the fact he is accessing to a property of a null object. so before doing that he have to check if the object is null, if not he can go forward and retrieve the answer from another table.

Comment: Thank you @alessio. This worked with no exceptions. :)

Answer (score 1):

For a standard way, you should check whether `answers` is null instead of `try catech exception`.

For Demo code like:

```
string answerText;
var answers = await _context.OfferedAnswers.FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id == answerId);
if(answers == null)
{
   var cols = await _context.Cols.FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id == answerId);
   answerText = cols.Label;
}
else
{ 
    answerText = answers.Value;
}
```

For another way, try linq query.

```
            var answerText =await (from f in _context.OfferedAnswers.Where(ft => ft.Id == id)
                          select f.Value)
                         .Union(
                          from s in _context.Cols.Where(st => st.Id == id)
                          select s.Label)
                         .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Comment: This works. Thank you. Can you please explain the difference in terms of efficiency? Which approach is better?

Comment: @NishanChathuranga I am afriad it depends on different scenario. For first way, it will run two queries if `answers ` is null. For second way, it will only run one time. But, its query is complex than first one. For better understanding, I would suggest you try first way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `answers.Value` and `answers.Label` return the same type, this is what I can think of off the top of my head. I haven't tried this before myself so it may/may not work. If it does work, you just need to figure out how to use the `await` keyword. Not sure if it can just be slapped on to the front or not.

`answerText = _context.OfferedAnswers.FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id == answerId) == null 
            ? answers.Label : answers.Value;`

Comment: Please let me know the result as I am genuinely curious if it works :)

Comment: Your answer assumes `answers.Label`` and `answers.Value` are gathered in the same call. Check that one is from `OfferedAnswers` and the other is from `Cols` so this won't solve the problem. Call Cols only in the event that OfferedAnswers fails and in that case use Label. Otherwise use the Value property from OfferedAnswers

Comment: Ah sorry you are correct. That's what I get for trying to answer something at midnight!

Comment: As @Fabulous said `Label` and `Value` are in different tables and same ID do not present in both tables. Thank you for trying to help. I appropriate your effort.